# How to install Jupyter(IPython) dependencies on elementary OS Freya

Tags: release-freya

Hi all and thanks for helping me out here!

I want to try [Jupyter Notebook (IPython)](http://jupyter.org/) on my elementary OS Freya installation, but to compile some Jupyter dependencies I also need `python3-dev` which I am not allowed to install by using apt.

Comment: which command you used? what is the error?

Comment: please let me know if you still have any errors =)

Comment: your problem solved ? @nodFlindors

Comment: @Ravan i lost a few days, because i removed python3 completely. I had to do a rollback installing ALL the packages that depend on python3.... now my system has other problems :) but i also did an upgrade and after that i could install jupyter and all the dependencies compiled.

Comment: thats fine =)...

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev
```

Note: (Use `python` instead of `python3` for legacy **Python 2**)

i.e.,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

**Alternative**:

I found a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1503382)..and solved the problem by  forcefully downgrading

```
  apt-get install -y \
 python3.4=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 \
 python3.4-minimal=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 \
 libpython3.4-stdlib=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 \
 libpython3.4-minimal=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1
```

**Note**: please note the removing packages before removing.

<sub>source [here](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html)</sub>

Comment: did you try that on your machine? i get an error telling me that i cannot install python3-dev because it depends on libpython3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) and python3.4-dev (>= 3.4.0-0~)  - two packages that should not be installed and are beeing kept back... i run a german system so the error message is also in german

Comment: @nodFlindors please see my edited answer..

Comment: @nodFlindors what is output of `python3 -V`

Comment: ok, so it works on your system. but what do i do? :) thats exactly what i tried.

Comment: python3 -V => Python 3.4.3

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev`...please comment result =)

Comment: @nodFlindors please see edited answer =)

Answer (score 1):

I successfully installed Jupyter using the python package management system PIP.

First install PIP for Python 3 from repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

then install Jupyter by using PIP:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
```

After Jupyter got successfully installed, you can start it from terminal:

```
jupyter notebook
```

[image: Jupyter]

Comment: well i tried that, but i get an error that i need libpython3-dev and python3.4-dev installed on my system so jupyter dependencies can be compiled during the pip install.

Comment: ah - you're on a german system! :)

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev       
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Comment: Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 python3.4-dev : Hängt ab von: python3.4 (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) aber 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1 soll installiert werden
                 Hängt ab von: libpython3.4-dev (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                 Hängt ab von: libpython3.4 (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) aber 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1 soll installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.

Comment: well, it seems that there is something wrong with your system... try running `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix the unresolved dependencies.

Comment: While I understand it may be easier for you personally to communicate in German, future users of the site are unlikely to be so inclined. Please try to keep recorded discussion in English.

Comment: @lewis you are right, its better for others to communicate in German. i was just saying that i am not able to produce an English apt-output.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Just a little note in English next time saying the same and that will be fine.